# net::ERR_CACHE_MISS Android webview flutter with <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Tags: android, flutter

I have application which use webview on flutter.

I bumped into this error when application is launched on device.

`net::ERR_CACHE_MISS`

I googled around and found many article says about putting this permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

However I already have this in `AndroidManfest.xml`

And it happens only when app is downloaded from `google play`.

I tried some ways. 1) 2) works and 3) not

1. Installing device with `flutter run` (it works)
2. make app bundle `fvm flutter build appbundle` with signature and get apk from bundle

   bundletool build-apks --bundle=build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab 
   --output=build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.apks 
   --ks=key/my-release-key.jks 
   --ks-pass=pass:mypass 
   --ks-key-alias=my-alias 
   --key-pass=pass:mypass

   then install `bundletool install-apks --apks=build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.apks`

   (it works)
3. install from `google play` (it shows error)

Is there any points, I should check??

`app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.guessdrawing">
    <!--THe Internet Permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <application
        android:label="My whatapp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the same trace to the manifest file in debug?
debug/androidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: If not, you can try to add the following permissions to the manifest:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

Comment: Thank you for your help .I tried the same but in vain. Also I update situation in articles. it happens only when app is downloaded from play store, if I directly install apk to devices it dosen't happen.